# Identifier expected.

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

This code gives me the "Identifier expected" message. I have highlighted the problematic lines (BirthDate.Text):

```
// Add user data to DB.
AddUser myUser = new AddUser();
bool addSuccess = myUser.AddUsr
(
    UserName.Text,
    PrefUserName.Text,
    OtherNames.Text,
    MaritalStatus.SelectedValue,
    SpouseName.Text,
    **BirthDate.Text,**
    Profession.Text,
    PostalAddress.Text,
    ResAddress.Text,
    Email.Text,
    PhoneNumber.Text,
    Church.Text,
    Gender.SelectedValue,
    HomeTown.Text,
    Area.Text,
    City.Text,
    Region.Text,
    Country.Text,
    Approved.Checked,
    ApprovedBy.Text,
    **DateCreated.Text,**
    RoleName.SelectedValue,
    Photos.FileName
);
```

This is the class code itself:

```
using System;
using MemberMgr.Models;
namespace MemberMgr.Logic
{
    public class AddUser
    {
        public bool AddUsr
        (
            string UserName, 
            string PrefUserName, 
            string OtherNames, 
            string MaritalStatus, 
            string SpouseName, 
            DateTime BirthDate, 
            string Profession, 
            string PostalAddress, 
            string ResAddress, 
            string Email, 
            string PhoneNumber, 
            string Church, 
            string Gender, 
            string HomeTown, 
            string Area, 
            string City, 
            string Region, 
            string Country, 
            bool Approved, 
            string ApprovedBy, 
            DateTime DateCreated, 
            string RoleName, 
            string Photos
        )
        {
            var myUser = new IdentityModels();
            myUser.UserName = UserName;
            myUser.PrefUserName = PrefUserName;
            myUser.OtherNames = OtherNames;
            myUser.MaritalStatus = MaritalStatus;
            myUser.SpouseName = SpouseName;
            myUser.BirthDate = BirthDate;
            myUser.Profession = Profession;
            myUser.PostalAddress = PostalAddress;
            myUser.ResAddress = ResAddress;
            myUser.Email = Email;
            myUser.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
            myUser.Church = Church;
            myUser.Gender = Gender;
            myUser.HomeTown = HomeTown;
            myUser.Area = Area;
            myUser.City = City;
            myUser.Region = Region;
            myUser.Country = Country;
            myUser.Approved = Approved;
            myUser.ApprovedBy = ApprovedBy;
            myUser.DateCreated = DateCreated;
            myUser.RoleName = RoleName;
            myUser.Photos = Photos;

            using (IdentityUserContext _db = new IdentityUserContext())
            {
                // Add User data to DB.
                _db.users.Add(myUser);
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }
            // Success.
            return true;
        }

    }
}
```

My senior programmers out there, kindly help me out. I know that TextBoxes accept the string data type and their contents should be Text. Am I missing something here?

Comment: How do you know that's the problem line?  I don't see how that would cause that compiler error. I could see where you'd need to _parse_ the text values to `DateTime`, but that's a _different_ compiler error.

Answer (score 0):

Your `DateCreated` and `BirthDate` are of type `DateTime`, `BirthDate.Text` and `DateCreated.Text` are of type `string`. You need to convert the `string` to `DateTime` e.g. with:

```
DateTime.Parse(DateCreated.Text)
```

or if the format is known:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(DateCreated.Text, "dd.MM.yyyy",
    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Hi Manfred Radlwimmer, I have tried your answer like this:                         DateCreated.(DateTime.ParseExact(DateCreated.Text, "dd.MM.yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)),
but still get the "Identifier expected" error. Compiler points to the first parenthesis (DateTime.P...) as the culprit.

Comment: Hi Manfred Radlwimmer, I did not implement your answer correctly at first. It has actually cleared the error message. Thanks a millions times.

Comment: @MusahYandar Glad I could help. If your question is answered, please use the "accept answer" button (checkmark on the left of the question) to mark to the question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Your `BirthDate` property is actually defined as a `DateTime` object as opposed to a string, so you will need to explicitly parse the Date from your TextBox for this to work as expected via the [`DateTime.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) methods :

```
bool addSuccess = myUser.AddUsr
(
     /* Omitted for brevity */
     DateTime.Parse(BirthDate.Text),
     /* Omitted for brevity */
);
```

or if you explicitly know the format it will be passed in, you could use :

```
// You can define a formatting string like "MM/dd/yyyy" that cooresponds to the format that
// you know your TextBox will use
DateTime.ParseExact(BirthDate.Text,"{format-string}",null);
```

The same issue applies to your `DateCreated` property which also expects to receive a `DateTime` object as opposed to the string that you are currently passing in

Comment: Hi Rion Williams, thanks a lot. The error message is cleared.